# Confuse about baseUrl in requirjs

Tags: requirejs, base-url

Here is my folder structure:

```
project
|---src
|   |---lib/require.js
|   |---object/extend.js
|   |---main.js
|
|---index.html
```

in the main.js, I import require.js and main.js, success:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/lib/require.js" data-main="src/main"></script>
```

then in the main.js , I try to import the extend.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'src'
});

require(["object/extend.js"], function (extend){

});
```

but it failed, it tell `404`, and I saw the request is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/object/extend.js
```

it seems the `baseUrl` doesn't work

so what's wrong with my code? How can I let the baseUrl work?

Comment: this wouldn't explain the exact error you see, but you should not have .js in your require. It should be `require(["object/extend"]` Also, I believe the base url is assumed to be same as the location of data-main script so your baseUrl in this case might be redundant.

Comment: @explunit: thank you, the problem is really the `.js`.You can give your comment as answer, and I will accept i.t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have .js in your require. It should be:

```
require(["object/extend"], function (extend){

});
```

When RequireJS sees a dot in the module name it appears to assume that this is a full URL and does not process the baseUrl, etc. Note, however, that you can still use a dot in the module name if you've defined it as a path mapping:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'a.b': 'libraries/something/a.b'
  }
});
```

and then later require it:

```
require(['a.b'], function (ab){

});
```